# Intellij cannot run Spring app with a certain dependency

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on a webapp with spring and maven and want to be able to run the application from within a local tomcat server and intellij. This dependency seems to be the culprit.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

when I remove this dependency the application runs fine in intellij because of the other dependency but then can't run on tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can I set something up to automatically use the right dependency for intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup maven profile in the pom.xml, then use specific profile for Intellij. Intellij allows you to select the profile while running the build.

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
    <id>intellij</id>
    …
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>…</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    …
 </profile>
 <profile>
    <id>release</id>
    …
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>…</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    …
 </profile>
```